# MS Access ORDER by row

Tags: c#, ms-access, sql-order-by

I'm try display data from column `points` ,`SELECT * from table ORDER by point` I want get number from max to min, but i get from min to max, how to fix it ?

Comment: To correctly answer, you should give us the text of your query and the datatype of the column points

Comment: @Steve, I believe that's more than obvious...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM yourtablename ORDER BY point DESC
```

Answer (score 2):

```
ORDER BY [columnName] DESC
```

is the answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try something like the following:

```
SELECT * from table ORDER by point DESC
```